# Run TaskCat with parameters file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

So I want to run taskcat tests with a parameter file but it doesn't seem to work, I have a setup like this but I keep getting errors:

```
├── .taskcat.yml
├── ci
│   ├── parameters.json
│   └── taskcat.yml
├── templates
    └── sqs-yaml.template
```

-taskcat.yml is:

```
global:
  qsname: sample-taskcat-project
  regions:    
    - us-east-1    
tests:  
  taskcat-yaml:
    parameter_input: parameters.json
    template_file: sqs.yml
    regions:
      - us-east-1
```

-.taskcat.yml is:

```
global:
  qsname: sample-taskcat-project
  regions:    
    - us-east-1    
tests:  
  taskcat-yaml:
    parameter_input: parameters.json
    template_file: sqs.yml
    regions:
      - us-east-1
```

-parameters.json is:

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "MyQueueName",
        "ParameterValue": "TestQueue"
    }
]
```

-sqs-yaml.template is:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Creates an SQS Queue.
Parameters:
  MyQueueName:
    Description: My Queue Name
    Type: String
Resources:
  MyQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      MyQueueName
Outputs:
  MyQueueARN:
    Value:
      Ref: MyQueue
```

Answer (score 2):

@Guzdo - Thanks for using taskcat. Github is the best support mechanism for taskcat.

That said, in v0.9.x, the entire configuration is now within the single config file. Looks like it's been auto-generated for you  - have a look at '.taskcat.yml'

Here are a few examples:

```
project:
  name:  my-cfn-project
  az_blacklist:
    - use1-az1
  build_submodules: false
  lambda_source_path:  functions/source
  lambda_zip_path: functions/packages
  owner: me@example.com
  package_lambda: false
  parameters:
    KeyPairName: blah
```

```
project:
  (...)
  tests:
    my-example-test:
      (...)
      parameters:
        KeyPairName: blah
```

More comprehensive example config:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taskcat/taskcat/master/tests/data/config_full_example/.taskcat.yml

Comment: So I altered my templates a bit and now I have .taskcat.yml, parameters.json and sqs.yml but it's still reading the default parameter value from inside the template, it's not reading from the external parameters file.